# Pretty Printing is not pretty at PythonTeX ?

Tags: best-practices, python

I try make LaTeX document with PythonTeX and this my MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\begin{document}
\section{Perhitungan Pangkat}
\paragraph{}
SymPy dapat melakukan perhitungan pangkat, namun perlu didefinisikan variabel yaitu sebagai berikut :
\begin{pyconsole}
from sympy import *
x,t,z,nu = symbols('x t z nu')
\end{pyconsole}
\paragraph{}
Untuk menampillkan \emph{pretty printing}, kita perlu menggunakan karakter yang didasarkan pada Unicode, dengan perintah berikut :
\begin{pyconsole}
init_printing(use_unicode=True)
\end{pyconsole}
\paragraph{}
Misalkan kita akan mencari suatu turunan dari $e^x\sin(x)$
\begin{pyconsole}
diff(sin(x)*exp(x),x)
\end{pyconsole}
\paragraph{}
Kita menghitung nilai suatu integral $\int (e^x \sin(x)+e^x \cos(x))dx$ :
\begin{pyconsole}
integrate(exp(x)*sin(x)+exp(x)*cos(x),x)
\end{pyconsole}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Hitung $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(x^2)dx$
\begin{pyconsole}
integrate(sin(x**2),(x,-oo,oo))
\end{pyconsole}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

After Compile it and get result like this :

[image: not pretty]

But, if I make it with Python IDLE  then I get result like this :

[image: pretty]

**How to resolve it for get result like at Python IDLE ? What problem available font or others?** I don't know about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a font issue. PythonTeX uses UTF8 by default, and all of the characters are coming through correctly. You need a monospace font that can correctly display all of the math characters. It *must* be a monospace font because otherwise the superscripts won't line up correctly (the superscripts are on the line above whatever they go with).

There are different ways to deal with this. Probably the simplest is to use **LuaLaTeX** with a monospace font that is as complete as possible. If you add this at the beginning of your preamble, MS Gothic will be used (assuming you have it). It gives a decent representation, although the division line is too long and there are some font warnings.

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{MS Gothic}
```

You could also use [GNU Unifont](http://unifoundry.com/unifont.html). It gives the most accurate representation I've found on my system, although there are still some font warnings.  And since it is a bitmap font, the appearance may not be what you want.

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{GNU Unifont}
```

[image]

There are likely other good font options as well. These are just the ones I had installed or could find quickly.

Comment: Are you aware of sympys capability to use latex for the output? `init_printing(use_latex=True)`

Comment: @MaxNoe I've integrated SymPy's LaTeX printer into the non-console parts of PythonTeX, but haven't yet tried to integrate it with the console (which is emulated with the `code` module). In this case, `init_printing(use_latex=True)` turns off the use of Unicode while maintaining pretty printing, which helps with the font issues. But it doesn't give actual LaTeX output. Actual LaTeX output can almost be obtained with something like `init_printing(pretty_print=False, str_printer=latex)`, except that it isn't rendered because of the way the console highlighting currently works. Should be fixable.